# Jquery ScrollTop not able to scroll up

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-animate, scrolltop

```js
$scope.$watch('data', function() {
    $("#pollingData").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() },40000);       
});
```

This code is working absolutely fine for me but when i manually scroll up my page from bottom scrollbar is flickering.I'm not able to scroll my page up.

Comment: Jquery has scrolling issue in older version. Which version are you using for jquery?

Comment: I'm using "2.1.4" version of Jquery.

Comment: ok then go through: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/6515 will fix your issue

Comment: or if possible update your jquery version